# Python プログラムを保存してターミナルで実行すると No such file or directory

Tags: python, python3

当方ものすごい初心者です
書籍『みんなのPython』通りにコマンド入力して⌘Cでデスクトップ上にファイル名 `draw_tree.py` とし保存したものの、ターミナルで `$ python draw_tree.py` と打ち込んでも書籍通りに turtle を起動し図を書き出せず、`No such file or directory`、つまりファイルがないというエラーが表示されてしまいます。ファイル名が悪いのかファイルの保存先が悪いのか、はたまた誤字脱字があるのか色々思考錯誤したのですがなかなか解決しない為書き込ませていただきます。親切な方いらっしゃいましたらご教授ください

[image: 書籍、みんなのPythonを参考に作成したプログラム]

Answer (score 3):

作成したファイル(draw_tree.py)はデスクトップに保存されたようですが、ターミナルを開いた直後はホームディレクトリにいる状態なので`$python ...`を実行してもファイルが見つからないのだと思います。

```
ファイルが保存されている場所
/User/ユーザ名/Desktop/draw_tree.py

ターミナルを開いた直後の居場所
/User/ユーザ名/
```

ターミナルで`cd Desktop`と実行してディレクトリを移動した後`ls`でファイル一覧を表示して、作成したファイルが見えているかを確認してください。
その後で再度`python draw_tree.py`を実行してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コメント通りcd desktopを実行し、ls -la~/desktopでファイル一覧を表示させたのですがファイルがやはりデスクトップにはないみたいなのでもう一度保存先について調べてみようと思います！anacondaに内蔵されているJupyter Notebookで同じプログラムを入力したら無事図を書き出すことができたのでやはり保存先に問題がありそうです！