# python にて　No such file or directoryと表示されます

Tags: python, csv

python というかプログラミング初心者です。ご回答頂けたら幸いです。以下のコードをatomに書いた後、デスクトップの自分のフォルダにcsvreader.pyという名前で保存しました。

```
import csv
f = open("csv_example.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
f.close()
```

このような内容で保存してAnaconda Promptで起動すると

```
(base)C:¥Users¥concrete-2>pythonC:¥Users¥concrete-2¥Desktop¥python¥csvreader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:¥Users¥concrete-2¥Desktop¥python¥csvreader.py", line3, in<module>
f = open("csv_example.csv", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Error 2]No such file or directory: 'csv_example.csv'
```

と毎回出てしまいます。
このエラーの意味するところ、また対処方法を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 重複候補 - [Python プログラムを保存してターミナルで実行すると No such file or directory](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/41268)

Answer (score 1):

> FileNotFoundError: [Error 2]No such file or directory: 'csv_example.csv'

英語で書かれている通り、csv_example.csvというファイルやディレクトリが見つからないというエラーです。

pythonプログラムの基本的な実行方法は、

```sh
python プログラム名.py
```

です。open関数で相対パスを指定した場合、この実行コマンドを実行したときのカレントディレクトリからの相対パスを意味しています。

例えば、現在いるディレクトリが`/home/user/Desktop/python`だとします。そして、`/home/user/Desktop/python/test1`に存在するcsvreader.pyを実行します。

```sh
python test1/csvreader.py
```

このとき、csv_example.csvは`/home/user/Desktop/python`に存在するべきなので、`/home/user/Desktop/python/test1`にある場合はファイルが見つからないというエラーが発生します。

このエラーを生じさせないためには、pythonコマンドを実行しているカレントディレクトリに`csv_example.csv`を配置する必要があります。

または、csv_example.csvの絶対パスを指定する方法があります。

Comment: pythonコマンドを実行しているカレントディレクトリに読み込みたいcsvファイルを設置できて、無事うまく読み込めました。丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございました。